# Помогите переписать скрипт с jquery на js

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

```
$('.call-me-modal').click(function () {
    var buttonId = $(this).attr('modal');
    $('#modal-container').removeAttr('class').addClass(buttonId);
    $('body').addClass('modal-active');
})

$('h1').click(function () {
    $('#modal-container').addClass('out');
    $('body').removeClass('modal-active');
});
```

Благодарю

Comment: [`Document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) в помощь

Comment: Руководство по преобразованию в общем случае: http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как то так:

```
const callMeModals = document.querySelectorAll('.call-me-modal');
[...callMeModals].forEach(modal => {
    const buttonId = modal.getAttribute('modal');
    const modalContainer = document.getElementById('modal-container');
    modalContainer.setAttribute('class', buttonId);
    document.body.classList.add('modal-active');
});

const titles = document.querySelector('h1');
[...titles].forEach(title => {
    const modalContainer = document.getElementById('modal-container');
    modalContainer.classList.add('out');
    document.body.classList.remove('modal-active');
});
```

`querySelectorAll` - возвращает коллекцию элементов, а не массив, поэтому для доступа к методу `forEach` используем `spread` оператор `[...]`, он превратит коллекцию в массив

**P.S.** 
`classList` вроде не шибко кроссбраузерный и вместо него можно использовать функцию хэлпер, которая будет работать через `set/getAttribute`, но это выходит за рамки вопроса ( сами )

Comment: ответ классный я 500 уроков посмотрел никак не мог понять этот spread оператор то есть понимал но не знал где использовать.Благодаря вам я теперь и знаю где и как его использовать спасибо огромное

Comment: @Избытоксусликов, да не за что)